# Rudin Exercise 2.7: union of subsets of a metric space, and closure thereof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to solve exercise 7 in Chapter 2 of Rudin and was hoping someone could look over my proof.

> Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots$ be subsets of a metric space.
>
> a) Let $B_n = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i$, prove that $\overline{B}_n = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{A}_i$, for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$
>
> b) If $B = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$, prove that $\overline{B} \supset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A}_i$.

Show, by an example, that this inclusion can be proper.

Here is my attempt.

> a) The closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing it. Thus, for all $i$, $\overline{A}_i$ is closed. Further, the finite union of closed sets is closed. Thus, $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{A}_i$ is closed. Furthermore, $\overline{A}_i = A_i \cup (A_i)'$, where $(A_i)'$ is the set of limit points of $A$. Thus, $A_i \subset \overline{A}_i$ for all $i$, which implies that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{A}_i$, i.e., $B_n \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{A}_i$. By Theorem $2.27$, for any metric space $X$ where $E, F \subset X$, if $E \subset F$ where $F$ is closed, then $\overline{E} \subset F$. Therefore, we deduce that $\overline{B}_n \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{A}_i$. Furthermore, 
>   $A_i \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i$ for any $i$, meaning that $A_i \subset B_n$ for any $i$. But $B_n \subset \overline{B}_n$, meaning that
>   \begin{align*}
> A_i \subset B_n \subset \overline{B}_n,
> \end{align*}
>   i.e., $A_i \subset \overline{B}_n$, where $\overline{B}_n$ is closed. Thus, Theorem 2.27 gives that $\overline{A}_i \subset \overline{B}_n$ for any $i$, and hence that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{A}_i \subset \overline{B}_n$.
>
> Thus, $\overline{B}_n \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{A}_i$ and $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{A}_i \subset \overline{B}_n$, so $\overline{B}_n = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{A}_i$.
>
> b) Let $B = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$. Since $A_i \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$, $A_i \subset B$. But $B \subset \overline{B}$, so 
>   \begin{align*}
> A_i \subset B \subset \overline{B},
> \end{align*}
>   hence, 
>   \begin{align*}
> A_i \subset \overline{B}.
> \end{align*}
>   But $\overline{B}$ is closed, so by Theorem $2.27$, we have
>   \begin{align*}
> \overline{A}_i \subset \overline{B},
> \end{align*}
>   for any $i$, which implies that
>   \begin{align*}
> \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A}_i \subset \overline{B},
> \end{align*}
>   which can be written as 
>   \begin{align*}
> \overline{B} \supset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A}_i.
> \end{align*}
>
> As for an example to show that this inclusion can be proper, let us consider: 
>   \begin{align*}
> A_i = \left[\frac{1}{i}, 1\right],
> \end{align*}
>   in which case each $A_i$ is closed, so $\overline{A}_i = A_i$, meaning that their infinite unions are the same. That is, 
>   \begin{align*}
> \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A}_i. 
> \end{align*}
>   However, we have: 
>   \begin{align*}
> \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{i}, 1\right] = (0,1]. 
> \end{align*}
>   However, for the left-hand side, we get: 
>   \begin{align*}
> B = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \implies \overline{B} = \overline{\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i} = \overline{(0,1]} = [0,1].
> \end{align*}
>   Since $(0,1] \subset [0,1]$, $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A_i}$ is properly contained in $B$.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that for part a) it suffices to show that $\overline{A_1\cup A_2} = \overline A_1\cup\overline A_2$ as the general case follows by induction.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't consider using induction. Is the proof that I wrote incorrect, though?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's incorrect, it could be shortened though. I just wanted to point that out since many such statements about $n$ objects can be simplified to the case where $n=2$ because of that.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for this. I will try to work out an inductive proof of this fact.

Comment: Also, both statements are true for arbitrary topological spaces, not just metric spaces. Keep that in mind for when you study topology.

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:proof-verification].  This implies that you *know* that your argument is flawed, and you are seeking feedback.  Editing your question to remove your solution invalidates the answers provided.  Please don't do this.

Answer (score 5):

For b) note that $A_i \subset B$ implies $\overline {A_i} \subset \overline {B}$ for all $i$. Hence $\bigcup _i\overline {A_i} \subset \overline {B}$.

Your counter-example is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you explain why $\overline{A}_i \subset \overline{B}$? Is the argument that $A_i \subset B \subset \overline{B}$, where $\overline{B}$ is closed, so theorem $2.27$ implies that $\overline{A}_i \subset \overline{B}$?

Comment: @Matt.P Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof of $\text{a)}$ is acceptable, but you can also prove it without (directly) using the definition of limit points or Theorem 2.27. You only need two propositions that you mentioned and accept as true:

Proposition 1: The finite union of closed sets is closed.

Proposition 2: The closure $\overline{A}$ of a set $A$ satisfies

$\tag 1  \overline{A} \text{ is a closed set}$

$\tag 2  A \subset \overline{A}$

$\tag 3  \text{IF } A \subset L \text{ and } L \text{ is closed THEN } \overline{A} \subset L$

Using just these propositions and simple concepts from elementary set theory, you can demonstrate that

$\tag 4 \overline{B}_n = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{A}_i$